# Integrating telepat-io in java struts enterprise application

Tags: javascript, maven, npm, integration, telepat

Our team has a Java Struts based J2EE enterprise application. This application currently has a static front end. Our team architect has decided to add Ajax and JavaScript based user authentication to our application. To this end, we want to make use of **telepat-io**.

Currently, our project uses Maven as the build tool.

My question is: is telepat-io available as a maven repository? Is so, which one?

Comment: look into mvnrepository.com

Answer (score 1):

Since [**telepat.io**](http://docs.telepat.io/intro.html#installation-configuration) runs over the **node.js** ecosystem, it is handled throuh [**npm**](https://www.npmjs.com/).
When you need to handle **npm** through **maven**, you can use the [**npm-maven-plugin**](https://github.com/mulesoft/npm-maven-plugin).